# Is showing single textarea at first then show other fields on comment form confusing?

Tags: comments, motivation

I want to make commenting **easy** in order to **motivate** the visitors of my website(s) to comment.

The default comment form includes a comment text area (multi-line) and 3 text fields.

[image]

I want to make the comment form as a **single text area**. If a visitor type anything **then** it shows the other fields.

I wonder if I make this form as below does it motivate the visitors (because there is only one text area to fill **at first**) or make them confusing because there is **no** name and e-mail address fields that makes his comment specific.

[image].

(Not registered users, there is only visitors and in order to comment a visitor should enter his name and e-mail address.)

### Is there any known case for this? Does making the comment form as that make commenters confusing?

Comment: I have seen this approach on a few sites and I think it may help with commenting. Either way, why don't you try some A/B testing and study the results with real data? after all, it's just a line of code to change to get back to default

Comment: @Devin, thanks. Yes, I can make some A/B testing but it may not show me the **'expected'** result because there is no hundred thousands of visitors. Asking to the 'experts' is first thing for me to do, then I will try some other things, A/B tests etc.

Comment: Asking "What do you think about this?" and "Which form makes you feel what? is a strong indicator that this question is "primarily opinion based". It looks like a survey. Perhaps you could compose a different question that extracts some key element of this and asks a question with a more objective answer.

Comment: Although this is a decent question at its root, right now you're essentially asking for opinions.  As a result I'm putting it on hold, but if you improve the question to be less about what we think or feel about it, you can ask for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is easier to fill in just comment. On the other hand, if name and email address are required, you might detract some users with a negative feeling in case they just filled in a comment but don't want to give you their email address.

Ideally apply this approach for users that are already logged in only. To the  anonymous you might want to offer an explanation why you need their address and little reward for entering it. You need to balance the negative impression you might cause with displaying required fields after they set to typing in their precious comment.

In case you need to know the exact insight into what will work best, the best solution for your situation - test on the real users, their motivation is what will guide you to the best solution.